# Search rectangle (hard disk) in the image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

**Task**: Find the hard disk in the image to determine its angle and contours

**Problem**: It is not always possible to find the correct contour of the disc.

In the code, I make images gray, blur, find the difference between them and define the contours, but the solution is not exact. I would like your help.

Second question:
Maybe I can detect my disk from this image? Can you help me with algorithm.

Background image:

[image]

Source image:

[image]

```
firstFrame = cv2.imread(bg_im)  # background image
frame_img = cv2.imread(frame)   # source image

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
firstFrame = cv2.cvtColor(firstFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
firstFrame = cv2.GaussianBlur(firstFrame, (21, 21), 0)

frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

c = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)

x1 = box[0][0]
x2 = box[1][0]
x4 = box[3][0]

y1 = box[0][1]
y2 = box[1][1]
y4 = box[3][1]

perimeter_1_4 = sqrt((x4 - x1)**2 + (y1 - y4)**2)
perimeter_1_2 = sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

box = np.int0(box)
corner = list(rect)[2]

if perimeter_1_4 > perimeter_1_2:
    corner = -(90 - corner)    

cv2.drawContours(frame_img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

Comment: there is no rectangle in your image because of lens distortion (major) and perspective distortion (minor).

Comment: Looks like a fairly wide angle (short FL) lens and those tend to have high distortion. If possible, use a longer FL lens, with the least amount of distortion. As Micka mentions, calibrate your camera/lens system, and apply corrections to the images, so you can feed your detection algorithm with the best possible input. The lighting seems poor as well. Based on those specular reflections, it seems like two adjacent point sources, fairly dim. For such reflective objects, a big bright diffuse panel light might be better (or perhaps dark field would make the drive stand out nicely?)